# Different results when using globals in a loop and separately

Tags: stata

I'm using a loop to display certain results that I have stored in different macros `x0`,`x1`,`x2` and so on.

When I run through a loop to display these macros, I get a different result from if I were to manually display them.

***In a Loop:***

```
forval j =1/30  {
  dis $x`j'
}
```

Output:

```
50001
50002
.
.
```

***Individually:***

```
dis $x1
```

Output:

```
200
```

(which is the correct value)

I also tried to declare `j` as a global and then `dis $x1$j` and it gives me the same result as the loop.

Why is this and how do I fix this in a loop?

Comment: For completeness you should have told us that you have also a global macro `x` which contains `5000`, Otherwise these results don't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a loop or not is nothing to do with your problem. You want nested evaluation but are asking for successive evaluation.

Consider these examples:

```
. global x = 42

. global x1 = 666

. local i = 1

. di "$x`i'"
421

. di "${x`i'}"
666
```

The first `display` shows the result of evaluating first the global `x` then the local `i`. That result is `42` followed immediately by `1`.

The second `display` shows the result of first evaluating

```
 x`i'
```

to get name `x1` and then of evaluating

```
$x1
```

to get the global in question. To force nested evaluation you need to use braces `{}` to tell Stata not to use the default successive evaluation.

Documented at 18.3.10 in https://www.stata.com/manuals/u18.pdf No budding Stata programmer can afford not to read this chapter again and again.